# Ruby: TDD Plus Coding

Tags: ruby, tdd

```
gem 'minitest', '~> 5.2'
# TDD

require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'minitest/pride'
require_relative 'kid'

class KidTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_kid_has_not_eaten_sugar
    kid = Kid.new
    assert_equal 0, kid.grams_of_sugar_eaten
  end

  def test_kid_gets_5_grams_from_eating_candy

    kid = Kid.new
    kid.eat_candy
    assert_equal 5, kid.grams_of_sugar_eaten

    5.times { kid.eat_candy }
    assert_equal 30, kid.grams_of_sugar_eaten
  end

  def test_kid_is_not_hyperactive

    kid = Kid.new
    refute kid.hyperactive?
  end

  def test_kid_is_hyperactive_after_60_grams_of_sugar

    kid = Kid.new
    11.times { kid.eat_candy }
    refute kid.hyperactive?, "Not hyperactive yet..."
    kid.eat_candy
    assert kid.hyperactive?, "OK, now the kid is hyperactive."
  end
end

# CODE

class Kid
  attr_reader :grams_of_sugar_eaten


  def initialize
    @grams_of_sugar_eaten = 0
  end

  def eat_candy(grams = 5)
    @grams_of_sugar_eaten += grams
  end

  def hyperactive?
    false
  end
end
```

Can anyone help direct me in the thinking that I should have as far as how to go about getting the 2nd test to pass and so on?

I'm not sure what to do make the test pass after the kid eats 5 grams of sugar and then after 5.times to have it pass after he eats 30 grams of sugar.

Appreciate any help

Comment: Please format your code snippets properly.

Comment: You need to add an `eat_candy` method to your `Kid` class that increases `@grams_of_sugar_eaten` by the right amount. Give that a try and then post a follow up if you get stuck.

Comment: I think I reedited the code to where it should be formatted properly, please let me know if it looks weird still.

Comment: I've added a eat_candy method, but am not sure what to do in order to increase the grams_of_sugar_eaten to 5 and then to 30 without messing up the first test

Comment: Hint: 5 * 6 = 30.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You've added `eat_candy` as an `attr_reader`, not a method. The `initialize` function here sets `eat_candy` to itself.

A possible fix:

```
class Kid
  attr_reader :grams_of_sugar_eaten

  def initialize
    @grams_of_sugar_eaten = 0
  end

  def eat_candy(grams = 5)
    @grams_of_sugar_eaten += grams
  end
end
```

Comment: ok that works, I appreciate the help. So for the eat_candy method, we're passing the argument of grams = 5 and then just having to adjust the amount of grams eaten by whatever increment was given?

Comment: Yeah, the `= 5` part means "default to 5", so if no argument is given that will be 5 grams. You could say `eat_candy(900)` to induce a sugar coma.

Comment: How would you go about solving the booleans issue in the last test? Any hints as far as addressing the hyperactivity initially and then having to deal with him becoming hyperactive?

Comment: That's technically another question, so might be worth re-posting and focusing on that angle.